# Uncaught TypeError in Google reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-framework, recaptcha

I'm loading reCAPTCHA via JavaScript
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js and am using jquery-1.5.2.min.js to communicate with a local PHP script which then validates the input via Google's recaptchalib.php and returns data to the JavaScript in JSON format.
It all works, but Google Chrome's Console reports an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null  recaptcha_ajax.js:15
Recaptcha._init_builtin_theme                                recaptcha_ajax.js:15
Recaptcha._finish_widget                                     recaptcha_ajax.js:19
Recaptcha.challenge_callback                                 recaptcha_ajax.js:13
(anonymous function)                                                 challenge:12
```

I would like to resolve that error but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: If you don't post any of your code it will likely be impossible for anybody to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I had hoped for general advice and got it. But you're right of course, the more info the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're passing it a nonexistent element to instantiate itself in. Are you sure you didn't misspell an `id` or something like that?

Comment: I forgot to remove old code and called Recaptcha.create(..) twice. Thanks for getting me to look more closely!

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the `id` of the div where you want to create the reCaptcha. Check if the `id` is correct. And before create the reCpatcha, check if that `id` really exists:

```
if($("#captcha").length) {
  Recaptcha.create("here_is_your_key", "captcha", {
    theme: "clean"
  });
}
```